# CLion MinGW freeglut opengl library linking

Tags: opengl, intellij-idea, libraries, clion

I am trying to follow [this guide](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/HowTo_OpenGL_C.html) to configure my freeglut and opengl .

I am used to the intellij enviroment via android studio so i would like to work in Clion.

I am stuck at the part....

> Libraries: the OpenGL library "libopengl32.a", GLU library
>   "libglu32.a" and GLUT library "libfreeglut.a" are kept in
>   "\lib" directory. This directory is in the implicit
>   library-path. Nonetheless, we need to include these libraries in
>   linking. They shall be referred to as "opengl32", "glu32", "freeglut"
>   without the prefix "lib" and suffix ".a".

how do i add this in Clion ?

Comment: what are you stuck at? what have you tried?

Comment: i can't find how to do the library linking...

Comment: Step 3 of  point 1.1

Comment: your question is where to find the libraries or where to put them?

Comment: You'll have to edit your `CMakeLists.txt` (this is what's used by CLion to handle your project) in order to link your program with OpenGL. Have a look at [this example](https://code.google.com/p/opengl-tutorial-org/source/browse/CMakeLists.txt) (from the [OpenGL-Tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/) website). Also check out [this tutorial](http://igorbarbosa.com/articles/how-to-use-opengl-freeglut-and-cmake/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLion uses cmake for building your projects. Follow below steps to add link libraries to your project.
Open the `CMakeLists.txt` file in your project and add,

```
target_link_libraries(<target executable> libopengl32.a libglu32.a libfreeglut.a)
```

to that file.

`target executable` is the executable which you want to link these libraries. Normally this is your project name as defined in `add_executable`.

**Note:** Cmake will show you an error if you place `target_link_libraries` before `add_executable`.